# MKMapView detecting left or right

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview, accessoryview

iOS 11.x Swift 4.0

Learning about mapview and created a pin with left and right accessoryviews with this code.

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {

    if annotation is MKUserLocation  {
        return nil
    }

    let reuseId = "pin"
    var pav:MKPinAnnotationView?
    if (pav == nil)
    {
        pav = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseId)
        pav?.isDraggable = true
        pav?.canShowCallout = true;
        pav?.rightCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton(type: .infoLight)
        pav?.leftCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton(type: .contactAdd)
    }
    else
    {
        pav?.annotation = annotation;
    }

    return pav;
}
```

Using this call to detect when you press on the infoLight and/or the contactAdd UIButtons. But I struggling to figure out how to tell which one was pressed? This call fires? But how to figure if it was the left or the right?

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {
    print("go figure annotationView \(view)")
    if (view.rightCalloutAccessoryView != nil) {
        print("right \(view.rightCalloutAccessoryView)")
    }
}
```

Obviously this is wrong, but how to know if the left or the right was tapped?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try following code:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {
    if view.rightCalloutAccessoryView == control {
        //right accessory
    } else {
        // left Accessory
    }
}
```

Comment: I like it but it's missing one minor item for completeness.  

if view.detailCalloutAccessoryView == control { return }

That needs to be above the if check as control has three types.

Answer (score 1):

You can cast the control as `UIButton` and check it's type

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {

    let btn  = control as! UIButton

    if(btn.buttonType == .infoLight)
    { 
        // right Accessory
    }
    else
    { 
        // left Accessory
    }

}
```

Comment: Sure this will work, but can I not detect the .infoLight and/or .contactAdd settings?

Comment: What do you mean by settings ?

Comment: Sorry Sh_Khan, Ariel has pipped you to the post!